# Issue with f:setPropertyActionListener and h:dataTable

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, jsf-1.2

I am trying to pass two parameters i.e. (`nomComposantARejouer`, `typeFileARejouer`) to an action method (`gestionnaireMessagesController.rejouerMessage`) using the `setPropertyActionListener` (we use jsf 1.2).

Here is the relevant jsp code:

```
<h:column>
<h:columnHeaderFacet>
<h:columnHeader value="#{msgs['pilotage.coordinateur.libelle.rejouer']}" />
</h:columnHeaderFacet>
<h:commandLink id="rejouer"
value="#{msgs['pilotage.coordinateur.libelle.rejouer']}"
action="#{gestionnaireMessagesController.rejouerMessage}">
<f:setPropertyActionListener
target="#{gestionnaireMessagesController.nomComposantARejouer}"
value="#{gestionnaireMessagesController.nomComposant}" />
<f:setPropertyActionListener
target="#{gestionnaireMessagesController.typeFileARejouer}"
value="#{gestionnaireMessagesController.typeFile}" />
</h:commandLink>
</h:column>
```

However, I always get a NPE because both parameters are null when used in the action method:

```
public String rejouerMessage() {
    log.debug("-->"+nomComposantARejouer);//null
    ParamResultatMessagesDTO message= (ParamResultatMessagesDTO) messagesTableau.getRowData();
    log.debug("MessageId: " + message.getMessageId());
    try {
        Pager p = Pager.getInstance();
        ParamRejouerMessageDTO prm = new ParamRejouerMessageDTO();
        prm.setMessageId(message.getMessageId());
        prm.setFileGet(nomsFilesMap.get(nomComposantARejouer).get(typeFileARejouer));
        prm.setFilePut(nomsFilesMap.get(nomComposantARejouer).get("TASKQ"));
        RejouerMessageService serv = (RejouerMessageService) this.getService(ServiceCst.REJOUER_MESSAGE_SERVICE);
        serv.rejouerMessage(prm);
    } catch (BusinessException e) {
        this.addMessage(e);
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        this.addMessage(e);
    }


    return chargerPage(); // TODO Navigation case.
}
```

I am not sure what I am getting wrong. Can anyone please help?

FYI, the variables `nomComposant` and `typeFile` can be displayed without problem and are not null.

Also ignore the h:columnHeaderFacet tags. They are inhouse tags that I've renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically doing:

```
gestionnaireMessagesController.setNomComposantARejouer(gestionnaireMessagesController.getNomComposant());
gestionnaireMessagesController.setTypeFileARejouer(gestionnaireMessagesController.getTypeFile());
```

during the invoke action phase of the form submit. Both properties are in the **same** bean instance and copied shortly before action method is invoked. This makes no sense. You seem to be expecting that the `value` is evaluated during the request of displaying the form. You seem to be thinking that `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` sets a request parameter. This is not true. The `<f:param>` is the only which does that.

So, this should do,

```
<f:param
    name="nomComposantARejouer"
    value="#{gestionnaireMessagesController.nomComposant}" />
<f:param
    name="typeFileARejouer"
    value="#{gestionnaireMessagesController.typeFile}" />
```

in combination with the following on `<managed-bean>` of `gestionnaireMessagesController` in `faces-conig.xml`:

```
<managed-property>
    <property-name>nomComposantARejouer</property-name>
    <value>#{param.nomComposantARejouer}</value>
</managed-property>
<managed-property>
    <property-name>typeFileARejouer</property-name>
    <value>#{param.typeFileARejouer}</value>
</managed-property>
```

*(you can if necessary remove `ARejouer` so that it reuses the same property)*

Answer (score 1):

I have often encountered this problem , it occours when there are two `f:setPropertyActionListener`.

You try in this way:

```
 <h:commandLink id="rejouer"
    value="#{msgs['pilotage.coordinateur.libelle.rejouer']}"
     action="#{gestionnaireMessagesController.rejouerMessage}"> <f:param
    name="nomComposant"
    value="#{gestionnaireMessagesController.nomComposant}"   />   
   <f:param name="typeFile"
    value="#{gestionnaireMessagesController.typeFile}" />   
  </h:commandLink>
```

Read this link: http://www.coderanch.com/t/211274/JSF/java/Passing-param-commandLink

Comment: thanks Michel. I researched the issue and came across this tutorial which seems to indicate that one can have several/multiple f:setPropertyActionListener for one commandLink. Have a look here and let me know what you think: [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#PassingActionParametersFromJSFToBackingBeans)

Comment: the problem with f:param is that retrieving the values tend to clutter the java code.

Comment: It seems that I am running into this problem because of the scope of my bean which is request. However I can't use @ViewScoped as I use jsf 1.2... I am stuck.

Comment: Yes it is true, but two  f:setPropertyActionListener in cascading don't work often correctly

Comment: You can try with session scope

Comment: SessionScope is not an option. Thanks anyway Michel.

Comment: The problem is not caused because there are two of them. The problem would still manifest with only one of it. The problem is caused because the purpose of the tag is misunderstood. See also my answer.